# Change entry in Column based on row index

Tags: python, pandas

I'm sure there is a simple way to do this but I'm spinning in circles, so I'm asking for help.

How can I code the following. If we use the df below. I want to select any row index over 29 and change the entry in the column called SUBREF to , the existing entry, (in this case Z009016 but that will change as the df is made by reading CSV files and the data will change) + '_V2'

So go from this

```
     SUBREF   SAMPNUM     MBID SRCEWELL DESTWELL
0   Z009016  80340796  1032810      C04       A2
1   Z009016  80340797  1032810      D04       B2
2   Z009016  80340798  1032810      B03       C2
3   Z009016  80340799  1032810      E03       D2
4   Z009016  80340800  1032810      C03       E2
5   Z009016  80340801  1032810      H04       F2
6   Z009016  80340802  1032810      E04       G2
7   Z009016  80340803  1032810      F03       H2
8   Z009016  80340804  1032810      D03       A3
9   Z009016  80340805  1032810      H03       B3
10  Z009016  80340806  1032810      A03       C3
11  Z009016  80340807  1032810      F05       D3
12  Z009016  80340808  1032810      D02       E3
13  Z009016  80340809  1032810      B02       F3
14  Z009016  80340810  1032810      G04       G3
15  Z009016  80340811  1032810      G03       H3
16  Z009016  80340812  1032810      A02       A4
17  Z009016  80340813  1032810      A01       B4
18  Z009016  80340814  1032810      H01       C4
19  Z009016  80340815  1032810      B04       D4
20  Z009016  80340816  1032810      C02       E4
21  Z009016  80340817  1032810      E01       F4
22  Z009016  80340818  1032810      E02       G4
23  Z009016  80340819  1032810      F02       H4
24  Z009016  80340820  1032810      E05       A5
25  Z009016  80340821  1032810      G02       B5
26  Z009016  80340822  1032810      D01       C5
27  Z009016  80340823  1032810      D05       D5
28  Z009016  80340824  1032810      F04       E5
29  Z009016  80340825  1032810      A04       F5
30  Z009016  80340826  1032810      B05       G5
31  Z009016  80340827  1032810      G01       H5
32  Z009016  80340828  1032810      A05       A6
33  Z009016  80340829  1032810      B01       B6
34  Z009016  80340830  1032810      H02       C6
35  Z009016  80340831  1032810      F01       D6
36  Z009016  80340832  1032810      C01       E6
37  Z009016  80340833  1032810      C05       F6
```

To this

```
     SUBREF      SAMPNUM     MBID SRCEWELL DESTWELL
0   Z009016     80340796  1032810      C04       A2
1   Z009016     80340797  1032810      D04       B2
2   Z009016     80340798  1032810      B03       C2
3   Z009016     80340799  1032810      E03       D2
4   Z009016     80340800  1032810      C03       E2
5   Z009016     80340801  1032810      H04       F2
6   Z009016     80340802  1032810      E04       G2
7   Z009016     80340803  1032810      F03       H2
8   Z009016     80340804  1032810      D03       A3
9   Z009016     80340805  1032810      H03       B3
10  Z009016     80340806  1032810      A03       C3
11  Z009016     80340807  1032810      F05       D3
12  Z009016     80340808  1032810      D02       E3
13  Z009016     80340809  1032810      B02       F3
14  Z009016     80340810  1032810      G04       G3
15  Z009016     80340811  1032810      G03       H3
16  Z009016     80340812  1032810      A02       A4
17  Z009016     80340813  1032810      A01       B4
18  Z009016     80340814  1032810      H01       C4
19  Z009016     80340815  1032810      B04       D4
20  Z009016     80340816  1032810      C02       E4
21  Z009016     80340817  1032810      E01       F4
22  Z009016     80340818  1032810      E02       G4
23  Z009016     80340819  1032810      F02       H4
24  Z009016     80340820  1032810      E05       A5
25  Z009016     80340821  1032810      G02       B5
26  Z009016     80340822  1032810      D01       C5
27  Z009016     80340823  1032810      D05       D5
28  Z009016     80340824  1032810      F04       E5
29  Z009016     80340825  1032810      A04       F5
30  Z009016_V2  80340826  1032810      B05       G5
31  Z009016_V2  80340827  1032810      G01       H5
32  Z009016_V2  80340828  1032810      A05       A6
33  Z009016_V2  80340829  1032810      B01       B6
34  Z009016_V2  80340830  1032810      H02       C6
35  Z009016_V2  80340831  1032810      F01       D6
36  Z009016_V2  80340832  1032810      C01       E6
37  Z009016_V2  80340833  1032810      C05       F6
```

Answer (score 2):

This Code will do the work:

```
**df.iloc[30:,0]=df.iloc[30:,0].apply(lambda x :str(x)+"V_2")**
```

We select the values with iloc operator and apply lambda function to add the string to it.

Comment: That's perfect. Thank you.  I was on the correct track but I couldn't work out how to combine iloc and lambda functions. I need to study them properly to better understand them.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`DataFrame.loc`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.loc.html):

```
df.loc[30:, 'SUBREF'] += '_V2'
```

Working like:

```
df.loc[30:, 'SUBREF'] = df.loc[30:, 'SUBREF'] + '_V2'
```

---

```
df.loc[30:, 'SUBREF'] += '_V2'
print (df.tail(10))
        SUBREF   SAMPNUM     MBID SRCEWELL DESTWELL
28     Z009016  80340824  1032810      F04       E5
29     Z009016  80340825  1032810      A04       F5
30  Z009016_V2  80340826  1032810      B05       G5
31  Z009016_V2  80340827  1032810      G01       H5
32  Z009016_V2  80340828  1032810      A05       A6
33  Z009016_V2  80340829  1032810      B01       B6
34  Z009016_V2  80340830  1032810      H02       C6
35  Z009016_V2  80340831  1032810      F01       D6
36  Z009016_V2  80340832  1032810      C01       E6
37  Z009016_V2  80340833  1032810      C05       F6
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether i understood your question right but this should give you the output you asked for.

for x in range(30,df.shape[0]):
df.iloc[x,0] += '_V2'